# Return Type information on Method Info

Tags: .net, reflection

Just had to perform some reflection and I noticed that `MethodInfo` had `ReturnParameter`, `ReturnType` and `ReturnTypeCustomAttributes`.

Now `ReturnParameter` contains the `ReturnType` and `ReturnTypeCustomAttributes`.  So shouldn't `ReturnType` and `ReturnTypeCustomAttributes` be marked as deprecated? or am I missing a point in there purpose somewhere.

- `ReturnParameter` was added in .net 2.0
- `ReturnType` was added in .net 1.0
- `ReturnCustomAttributes` was added in .net 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReturnParameter seems to be a wrapper over return type and attributes. Looks like it has been added for convenience of some sort:

> Compiler designers can use the ParameterInfo object returned by this
>   property to discover whether custom modifiers, such as
>   IsConstModifier, have been applied to the return type.

Funny that IsConstModifier is deprecated itself.

So I'd continue using ReturnType.

(Just checked usage in system libraries used for the current project. ReturnParameter is used 8 times, ReturnType - more than 200).

Comment: Seems to me like a refactoring idea got into the API.  Well at least that sums it up ReturnType is the common method.